# Distance between BLE device and paired device(android)

Tags: android, bluetooth-lowenergy, iot, beacon

I am trying to get distance between a BLE device(Beacon) and my Android mobile, which is paired to that beacon. I am using the following snippet

**Snippet**:

```
private double getDistance(int rssi, int txPower) 
{
 return Math.pow(10d, ((double) txPower - rssi) / (10 * 2));
}
```

For rssi i am using the device's RSSI but for txpower by default i am using "1". The return i am getting is similar to "464.2345" in long. so now my question is,

**1.What should be given as input in txpower and how?**

**2.How to convert the return values to meters?**

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You will never get distance through RSSI, mission impossible

Comment: Okay is there any other way to get distance? @AlexanderFarber

Comment: No comment on the formula (something like the inverse square law could be used) but basically the approach is right. The ratio RSSI/TxPower is proportional to the distance. But the TxPower should be a calibrated value stored on the beacon and you should read it from the beacon's advertisement data when scanning it. Is it an iBeacon, Eddystone beacon, AltBeacon or something else?

Comment: [this](https://www.snapdeal.com/product/yuron-black-bluetooth-device/678404793585#bcrumbSearch:bluetooth%20devices) is the device i am using, and can you please help me in reading the calibrated txpower from the device @MarkusKauppinen

Comment: I'm not familiar with that device, it apparently doesn't follow any Bluetooth beacon standard and it might not have any calibrated TxPower value available. In actual Bluetooth beacons the TxPower is the measured signal strength (like RSSI) at 1 meter distance. You can measure the device's RSSI at 1 meter (use the average of several measurements) and use that as the TxPower value. Then you have a calibrated reference value.

Comment: Ok forget about beacons, is there any way to calculate distance between a BLE device and its paired mobile? If so can you pls provide me with links? @MarkusKauppinen

Comment: Like I said, measure the RSSI at 1 meter distance and use it as the TxPower value.